# React Typescript: different clickhandler on specific parts of same div

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts

I'm new to React and Typescript and Coding in general so I'm not sure if that what I'm trying to do is even possible. I have a donut chart with clickable segments. it's from a minimal pie chart: https://github.com/toomuchdesign/react-minimal-pie-chart.

[image: here is the chart]

So as you see the chart is round but the container is square. When I click on the segment I can check other statistics. but i want to reset it when I click on some empty place. Right now with the clickawaylistener from material UI or my own clickhandler i have to move the mouse outside of the square and can't just click next to the segments to reset since the clickaway is outside of the element. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

this is my chart with the onClick handler:

```
<PieChart
  className={classes.chart}
  onClick={handleSegment}
  segmentsStyle={handleSegmentsCSS}
  lineWidth={20}
  label={handleChartLabels}
  labelStyle={{
    fontSize: "3px",
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    textTransform: "capitalize",
  }}
  labelPosition={115}
  paddingAngle={5}
  radius={30}
  data={data}
  animate
  animationDuration={500}
  animationEasing="ease-out"
/>;
```

And this my Clickhandler:

```
const handleSegment = (event: any, index: any) => {
    const values = Object.values(SegementDataType).map((value, index) => ({
        index,
        value,
    }));
    setSegmentValue(values[index].value);
    setStyles(segmentStyle);
    setSelectedSegmentIndex(
        index === selectedSegment ? undefined : index
    );
};
```

And my Clickawaylistener is just a function to set initial values

Comment: Could you provide some code? We could help you in a better way. From what I understand so far, I think you could add a custom data attribute for each segment, something like `data-segment-id={0,1,2}`. Then, in the `click` listener, you can obtain on which segment you have clicked via `e.target.closest("[data-segment-id]");`

Comment: i just edited and pasted my code. sorry im new here and learning. :D

Comment: I would really need a working example, for instance in codesandbox. I don't know how the `<PieChart>` component renders its children, and how it handles the click (one handler on the whole component, one handler for each segment, ..). I could make some test if I had a working example.

Comment: this is what i found. in there are a few pie charts and one is minimal piechart which im using. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/41ovg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, honestly, I don't have a lot to work with (the link you posted on the comment is a not-working example).
Though, I managed to understand something from here: https://toomuchdesign.github.io/react-minimal-pie-chart/index.html?path=/story/pie-chart--full-option

Anyways, try to:

1. Wraps the `<PieChart>` component into an element (`<div>`, for instance).
2. Adds an event listener on that wrapper element.
3. In the listener, check if a `path` has been clicked or not. If not, you can deselect the item.

Something like this:

```
    const divRef = useRef();

    const handler = (e) => {
        const divDOM = divRef.current;
        const closestPath = e.current.closest('path');

        if (closestPath != null && divDOM.contains(closestPath)) {
            // Here, a segment has been clicked.
        }
        else {
            // Here, a segment has NOT been clicked.
        }
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handler} ref={divRef}>
            <PieChart ... />
        </div>
    );
```

I also check that `divDOM` contains `closestPath` so that we are sure we are talking about a `path` belonging to the `<PieChart>`.

Though, this solution does not fix the problem that, INSIDE the `<PieChart>` component, the segment remains clicked. I don't think this can be fixed because of the implementation of the chart (it's a stateful component, unfortunately).

What you can try is to mimic a click on the selected path, but I don't think it will work